# arduino settings for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-ide

This is driving me crazy!  I see solutions all over the web and I still can't get this to work.  Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
    },
    "arduino.additionalUrls": "",
    "arduino.path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino",
    "arduino.commandPath": "arduino.exe",
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
}
```

I am running on Windows 10 and Arduino is installed in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino
```

I have four executables there:

- arduino.exe
- arduino_debug.exe (I downloaded this for good measure!)
- arduino-cli.exe
- uninstall.exe

When I click "Select Programmer" in VSC, I get"

```
 "Cannot find Arduino IDE. Please specify the "arduino.path" in the User Settings. Requires a restart after change.
```

- I have restarted the IDE and still get the same problem.
- I have rebooted the laptop.
- I have tried uninstalling both VSC and Arduino.

The Arduino IDE works fine stand-alone.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  I finally stumbled on these installation instructions:
https://nortronics.com.au/setting-up-visual-studio-code-for-arduino-programming/

This is what my .vscode/settings.json (you can find it in the left pane under .vscode in your project folder) now looks like:

```
{
    "arduino.path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Disabled",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
    "arduino.enableUSBDetection": true,
}
```